# How to read unzipped shapefiles from s3 bucket mounted onto aws windows ec2 instance and open as geodataframe?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, geopandas

I have an unzipped shapefile stored in an s3 bucket that is mounted as a drive onto an ec2 windows virtual machine. The s3 bucket is mounted as the K drive on the virtual machine. I am trying to read the shapefile from the s3 bucket and open it as a geodataframe in jupyter notebook. Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
path = r'K:\NY TEST DATA\Counties\NY_Counties.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(path)
gdf
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> DriverError: K:\NY TEST DATA\Counties\NY_Counties.shp: No such file or directory

I am able to write shapefiles to the mapped s3 bucket and that works just fine, but I'm not able to read shapefiles that are stored in the bucket. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "s3 bucket mounted as a drive"? How is that set up?